# вывести ответ на get запрос в виде json и html

Tags: php, json, curl, get

Задача делается для 2 сайтов: нужно отправить get запрос в php скрипте и получить ответ сервера с json/html данными.

Подробнее о задаче, что требуется получить в итоге:

1 сайт: отправляю get запрос на https://site.ru/folder1/folder2/name/folder3/1234567890?async получаю ответ json в формате { info }

2 сайт: отправляю get запрос на https://site.com/folder/1234567890?l=ru&pagev6=true получаю ответ html в формате < div>text< /div>

В чём требуется помощь:
запрос отправляю, но не могу понять почему кроме заголовков сервера, которые при сравнении с ответом сайта из браузера - правильные, не выводятся данные json и html.
Я уже пробовал и file_get_contents, и json_decode, и var_dump, а в ответ получаю Null.

Код для 1 сайта, где требуется получить ответ с json данными:

```
<?php
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);

    function curl_get($host = null){
    $ch = curl_init();

     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
             "Host: site.ru",
             "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36 OPR/52.0.2871.64",
             "Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
             "Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7",
             "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br",
             "Connection: keep-alive",
             "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest",
             "Referer: https://site.ru/folder1/folder2/name"
         ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    echo curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $html;
}

$urlp1 = 'https://site.ru/folder1/folder2/name/folder3/';
$urlp2 = '1234567890';
$urlp3 = '?async';
$urlpage = $urlp1.$urlp2.$urlp3;

$result = curl_get($urlpage);

print_r(iconv("utf-8", "cp1251", $result));
?>
```

Comment: $result вардампили до конвертации в другую кодировку? Может быть из-за этого нет контента?

Comment: Спасибо, хоть что-то появилось.
Сейчас попробую сконвертировать это в читабельный вид.

Comment: В общем я наконец разобрался, спустя кучу времени...даже стыдно сказать сколько я на это потратил.

Оказалось, что строчку 
"Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br"
нужно удалить вообще, иначе танец с бубном гарантирован.
а эта строчка
print_r(iconv("utf-8", "cp1251", $result));
 и вовсе не нужна так как всё итак прекрасно читается и её можно заменить на
echo $result;